# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data version=2.0.0.0' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm getting the following error message in one of my customer machine (Platform: Windows 8).

> "**Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data version=2.0.0.0' or one
>   of its dependencies**"

I reinstalled .Net framework 3.5 but no clue. I don't know how to resolve the this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution explorer...

Goto "Refrences" and  Right click, and "add refrences" then Go to ".Net" Tab and add "System.Data.Entity".

after that please rebuild your application / or clean and build

Comment: Is this the only solution for my problem? because I'm getting this exception in my customer machine.

Comment: mmm if you can see your program folder on your customers machine please check available dll files. (this may not be an option for all the issues like this some times I 've experienced dll issues like this and solve them by adding required dlls to bin directory)

Comment: Still i have the same issue. What will do for that?